# Or and Return value clarification

Tags: objective-c

I'm still learning objective-C and this code seems odd and hard to get a good search result with.

```
@interface Practice : NSObject 
{
   NSString *name;
   NSString *sortKey;
}

- (NSComparisonResult)sortPack:(Practice *)other
{
    return [[self sortKeyOrName] caseInsensitiveCompare:[other sortKeyOrName]]; 
}
```

Here's my question:

1. the "Or" in [self sortKeyOrName] can either be the two variables? If so, how can it determine which variable to take?
2. how does the process works in this call? Here's my take on this, it compares other and sortKeyOrName then returns if its asc, desc, or the same and does the value returned assigned to [self sorkeyOrName]?

Thank you.

Comment: From where u get this code?

Comment: Have a read of this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/ mainly "methods and messaging."

Comment: `name` and `sortKey` have nothing to do with `sortPack` function. `[self sortkeyOrName]` is a method call. The result of `[[self sortKeyOrName] caseInsensitiveCompare:[other sortKeyOrName]];` will be returned as a `NSComparisonResult` to whatever calls the `sortPack:` method.

Comment: Thanks Popeye for the link. It explains alot of my problems.

@CRDave - a random search of sample objective-c codes for practicing purposes only.

Comment: Popey comment solve my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would recommend reading [Learning Objective-c](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/) clearly you don't fully understand the language, but than again I have been doing it for years now and I don't fully understand the language.

The Instance variables `name` and `sortKey` have nothing to do with the method `sortPack:`. So **NO** "Or" doesn't mean it can be either of the two variables, `sortKeyOrName` is a method call.

A method is made up of three components the first one is the return type so in the case of `sortPack:` the return type is `NSComparisonResult`. Then there is a method name `sortPack` and finally the arguments `other` which has to be a `Practise *` object.

So you would call this method like `NSComparisonResult result = [self sortPack:object];`

So knowing this we can now look at what the body of this method is doing, because we now that `sortPack` returns a `NSComparisonResult` that means `[[self sortKeyOrName] caseInsensitiveCompare:[other sortKeyOrName]];` must return a `NSComparisonResult` as well.

What this `[[self sortKeyOrName] caseInsensitiveCompare:[other sortKeyOrName]];` is doing is first getting some result from `[self sortKeyOrName]` as this is a method call that returns something then it is comparing it to what ever is being returned from `[other sortKeyOrName]` which is also another method call that returns something. So we could look at it as if it is comparing `[@"SomeString" caseInsensitiveCompare:@"AnotherString"];` (Not sure what the two methods return so guessing strings)

Once these two have been compared it will then return the result from `sortPack` as a `NSComparisonResult`.

Hopefully you got a better understanding of this from the link.